# how to connect to a remote mongodb server (hosted on google cloud)?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, google-cloud-platform

I hope you can help me on this particular problem.

I use a windows virtual machine hosted on google cloud to stream some twitter data using the python code suggested here danielforsyth.me/analyzing-a-nhl-playoff-game-with-twitter.

The twitter data is stored in a local mongodb data. So far so good. Problem is: I would like to access this data remotely. I tried (without success) to locate the mongodb data path on a dropbox folder, but I am unable to use the resulting files.

Someone suggested that I should use a client to connect to my mongodb setup on google cloud, but I have no idea how to do that. Should I use the IP of the distant google cloud machine? What is the syntax to use in this case?

Any help appreciated!